# Mod Rewrite php htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use clean urls on my website for better SEO. I'M doing so doing using mod rewrite with htaccess. The Url is as follows `http://mywebsite.com/s.php?share=100` and I would like to accept urls like `http://mywebsite.com/s/100` or whatever number a user chooses. I'm using this rewrite regex expression but it is not working as expected

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
   RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /$1/$2.php 
   RewriteRule ^share/([^/]*)$ /s.php?share=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone point me as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You want your URL to look like `http://mywebsite.com/s/100`, meaning the URI is `/s/100`, but your pattern looks like `^share/([^/]*)$`. Since the URI doesn't begin with "**share**", that pattern will *never* match the URI that you want. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^s/([^/]*)$ /s.php?share=$1 [L]
```

Also, since you are requesting `/s/` and have a file called `/s.php`, you need to make sure **Multiviews** is turned off:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

So altogether, something like:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /$1/$2.php 
RewriteRule ^s/([^/]*)$ /s.php?share=$1 [L]
```